# Why is the following method incorrect in Java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

When I typed in the following method and compiled it in Java, I got "error: unreachable statement", why ?

```
  String getRankChar(int rank,boolean isFront)
  {
    switch (rank)
    {
      case 0 : return isFront?"<":">";break;
      case 1 : return isFront?"[":"]";break;
      case 2 : return isFront?"[":"]";break;
      case 3 : return isFront?"(":")";break;
      case 4 : return isFront?"(":")";break;
      default : return " ";break;
    }
}
```

Comment: because the cursor exits the block after return is called

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got a `break` statement after each `return` statement. *All* those `break` statements are unreachable, precisely because you return before each of them.

As per [section 14.21](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21) of the JLS:

> It is a compile-time error if a statement cannot be executed because it is unreachable.

And:

> [...] Every other statement S in a non-empty block that is not a switch block is reachable iff the statement preceding S can complete normally.
>
> ...
>
> A `break`, `continue`, `return`, or `throw` statement cannot complete normally.

The `return` statement cannot complete normally, so the `break` statement is unreachable (for each of your cases).

Just remove the `break` statements and it'll be fine.

Comment: Just curious: I know these rules as well, but I don't know where every rule is explained or clarified in the JLS. So my question is: do you know more or less where every subject is located in the JLS?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: Nope, but I can normally find it from the table of contents pretty quickly. I'm getting quite good at navigating language specs, although I find the C# spec much easier than the Java one on that front.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yeah, I would be able to do that as well. But you were just so fast that I thought you simply have a rough idea of what to find where in the table of contents. Within two minutes a nicely formed answer, with references to the JLS.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: Well I do have a bookmark for the JLS. That helps :)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I tried posting an answer as quick as possible with lots of references to the JLS, and I have to say: It works :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729588/wrong-type-in-java-conditional-assignment

Answer (score 2):

Because the break statement in the default case will never be executed since it will always return " " and exit the method.

Answer (score 1):

Because you `return` and then `break`. Returning already quits the method, so the `break` statement is unreachable.

Comment: Jon's here.  The rest of us can all go home now!

Comment: @DavidWallace I'm here too. So don't worry at all :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun Haha =)

Comment: I just though it was going to be funny to look at the voting race for my answer the one from Jon, since we answered within the same 10 seconds, but... No, everyone is voting for him. :)

Answer (score 1):

The break statement in each line cannot be reached because you do a return before.

Answer (score 0):

The code after return statement is un reachable, so remove anything that is after return statement.

Because, after you return, thre is nothing to execute.

Answer (score 0):

`return` stops executing the function.
Therefore, all of your `break`s can never be executed.

`break` isn't a magic incantation that ends a `case`; it's just a way to make sure that control doesn't flow through.
If you use a different statement that stops control flow (`return`, `continue`, or `throw`), you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

return means to exit the point from where the method was called

and the pointer doesnt proceeds any further

thus your program will never reach your `break` statement in any  case

thus the error