# Wrong type in Java conditional assignment

Tags: java, conditional-operator

In the following code I have two identical conditional assignment operations, one returns an object of type Double, and the second returns the String "Integer".

```
double d = 24.0;

Number o = (d % 1 == 0) ? new Double(d).intValue() : new Double(d).doubleValue();
String result = (d % 1 == 0) ? "Integer" : "Double";

System.out.println(o.getClass()); // prints "class java.lang.Double"
System.out.println(result); // Integer
```

Why are the exact same expressions returning two different things?

Comment: Interesting, it seems to be the Number o is whatever it "most compilcatedly" could be, irrespective to what it actually is. You can replace new Double(d).intValue()  with 1 and new Double(d).doubleValue() with 2.0 and get the same result. And I have confirmed that 1 is what actually goes into o

Comment: On the other hand changing new Double(d).doubleValue() to new Double(d).intValue() gives the result Integer, even though the other size of the : is never used

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

Comment: So its not based on complexity, just on whatever's in that last position?

Comment: As an asside; a traditional If statement behaves normally

Comment: @RichardTingle And here we all thought that `?:` behaved the same as an if statement

Comment: I pretty much thought it was a more compact version of a simple if statement!

Comment: An `if` statement and the ternary operator `?:` are different beasts. The former is a statement and as such has no value; the latter is an expression, and as such has a value, and that value needs a type -- the type chosen is basically the most specific type that applies to both "branches" of the ternary.

Comment: It makes sense once you understand it, but I can see how easy it would be to get burnt by it

Comment: Thanks @Cruncher, I'm quite impressed that it took SO all of 30 seconds to solve!

Comment: I think in the first case the type of the result of the evaluation of the ternary expression is `double`, but it gets autoboxed to `Double` because the type of the variable itself is `Number`.

Comment: @BheshGurung so it goes through two changes. Promotion from `int` to `double` because of the ternary operator, and then autoboxing to `Double` because it is being assigned to a `Number`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, that is because of the [JLS specs for the conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:
>
> - ...
> - Otherwise, binary **numeric promotion ([§5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)) is applied** to the operand types, and the
>     type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second
>     and third operands.

Numeric promotion is defined here in [§5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). It says:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>   both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - **If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.**
> - ...

Comment: Thanks Martijn, very nice catch.

Comment: @SamuelO'Malley - You could "fix" it to get your expected output by casting both results of the ternary operation to `Number`, which will eliminate the need for the compiler to do numeric promotion: `Number o = (d % 1 == 0) ? (Number)new Double(d).intValue() : (Number)new Double(d).doubleValue();`

Comment: @DaoWen wow you're right. Output: `class java.lang.Integer, Integer`

Comment: It's the conditional operator. It happens to be the only ternary operator at the moment, but that's not its name. That's why the link you've got is to "Conditional Operator ? :" rather than "Ternary Operator ? :"

Comment: @JonSkeet: Nice! I didn't really realize that ternary operator just means that it has three operands. I'll edit.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux: Yup - it's the equivalent of "unary" and "binary" but for three. It's a pet peeve of mine, and I'm longing for Java and C# to introduce another ternary operator just to make all previous statements about "the ternary operator" ambiguous :)

Comment: +1 For correctness, citation of standard, and for teaching me The Truth Behind Ternary :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Meh, it's a bit pedantic if you ask me. :) It's the only ternary operator, and as such is _the_ ternary operator as well as being _a_ ternary operator. If people leave off the emphasis on "_the_", that's fine with me. It's a bit like saying "the president" even though multiple presidents are possible in theory (and happen in practice, which is more than can be said of the ternary in Java!). That said, I do agree that people should know what ternary means. :)

Comment: @yshavit: But wouldn't it be more useful to use the *name* of the operator? Is the most important thing about it really that it just has three operands? My objection is partly that people believe that "the ternary operator" really *is* its name, when it's just not.

Comment: @JonSkeet In this case, it's exactly as useful to use the name (which resolves it to a single operator) vs its category (which resolves it to the same, single operator). I say "ternary operator" because "ternary" is a lot more fun a word than "conditional," and I don't otherwise get any chances to say "ternary" in my life. :) Maybe I should count in base 3 more often. But yes, I agree that people should know that it's actually called the conditional operator. If you lobby to add a second ternary operator out of spite, I'll lobby to add a second conditional operator. ;)

Comment: That said, we've all got our pet peeves, and I certainly wouldn't begrudge you yours.

Comment: @yshavit Adding a second conditional operator would be nonsense. That would be like adding another "Addition" operator. Names are supposed to be unique.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree, the name is better. However I'm guilty of calling it ternary. That's how I was introduced to it, and used it for a long time before learning it's real name. Also practically speaking, people will more likely know what you mean when you say "ternary" operator than if you say conditional. It's a sad truth. Also, I can't immediately think of another ternary operator that could be useful :)

Comment: @Cruncher Point is, they could change the name (e.g. "branching conditional operator" for `?:`, and "dereferencing conditional operator" for what Groovy and Kotlin call the Elvis operator). It was a joke, though: if JonSkeet wants to change the JLS just so that "ternary operator" just so that becomes an invalid identifier, then I'll want to change it so that "conditional operator" becomes an invalid identifier.

Comment: @yshavit Actually interestingly enough, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28 this seems to call it the `ternary conditional operator`. Probably to avoid ambiguity with the `conditional-and` and `conditional-or` operators.

Comment: @Cruncher Well, so there you go. :) See, even its name is ambiguous in practice! Ternary ftw.

Comment: @Cruncher: To disambiguate it there, I'd use "the conditional ?: operator" - or *possibly* "the ternary conditional operator". But I still think it's important for people to understand the difference between an operator's *name* and the adjective which just says how many operands it has.

Answer (score -3):

Well 0.0 is still == to 0

```
System.out.println(0 == 0.0); // equals true
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25

Comment: This question is related to the type of a Boxed primative, not value

Comment: And yet, `Double.valueOf(0).equals(Integer.valueOf(0))` is `false` -- and that's closer to the OP's situation.

Comment: The type of a variable can be important to a values behaviour. For example 2/4==0, whereas 2.0/4.0==0.5. As such this is not purely academic

Comment: Also, note that `0 == 0.0` is only true because the left-hand side is promoted to a double (of value `0.0)`. If you'd tried to do something like `int i = true ? 0 : 0.0` then you'd get a compile-time error, since `true ? 0 : 0.0` has a type of `double`, which can't be assigned to `int` without explicit casting.