# Can someone explain this syntax or provide a link that will explain this?

Tags: java, android

I do not understand what this statment is doing.

```
(minute==minuteFloor+1 ? TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL : 0)
```

could someone explain it or provide a link

Thank you.

Comment: Search for "Ternary" operator in Java.

Comment: result = testCondition ? value1 : value2

Comment: @PradeepSimha Strictly speaking this is the conditional operator, any operator with 3 arguments is a Ternary operator  (but java currently only has 1 Ternary operator; the conditional operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's basically

```
if(minute == minuteFloor + 1) {
 val = TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL;
} else {
 val = 0;
}
```

Comment: Almost, but not quite, `Number n=(true?1:1.5);` will have `n` of type Double so the two are not strictly equivalent. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19729588/wrong-type-in-java-conditional-assignment) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
myvariable  =   (minute==minuteFloor+1 ? TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL : 0)
```

In the above statement you used ?: operator which is called Ternary Operator.

it is used in below context:

```
if(condition)
{
//assign some value
}
else
{
//assign some other value
}
```

so your code does similar to below:

```
if(minute==minuteFloor+1)
{
myvariable=TIME_PICKER_INTERVAL;
}
else
{
myvariable=0;
}
```